# Video file is stuck at 0% when being uploaded via YouTube API V3 with Python (Resumable Uploads)

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I'm uploading a resumable video on YouTube using YouTube API V3. When the code is executed, the status_code in response is 200 (but according to Official documentation, 201 is needed if the API works fine ).
When I open the YouTube channel, the video is there showing "0 % processing".
Moreover, after sometime there's a message "Processing abandoned" (as in the screenshot attached).
I have tried to include the parameters needed in the script, but nothing is working to change the processing level of video on YouTube channel.
The code here is as given below:

```
import requests
import json
import httplib2
import sys

class youtube:
    #Access token obtained from OAuth 2.0 Playground
    token = 'ya29.a0Af................................'

    def resumable_uploads(self):
    
        token = self.token
        url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status,contentDetails'
        headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token), 'host': 'www.googleapis.com', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'X-Upload-Content-Type': 'video/*'}
    
        body = {
                "snippet": {
                    "title": "Video 2 by Sidra ",
                    "description": "This is a description of my video",
                    "tags": ["cool", "video", "more keywords"],
                    "categoryId": 22
                },
                "status": {
                    "privacyStatus": "public",
                    "embeddable": True,
                    "license": "youtube",
                    "selfDeclaredMadeForKids" : True
                }
            }
        response = requests.request('POST', url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(body))
        print("status_code: ", response.status_code)
    
        if response.status_code == 200: 
        
            location = response.headers['location']
            headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token),'content-type': 'video/*'}
        
            #converting file into Bytes
            video_file= open("testVideo.mp4", "rb")
            file_content = video_file.read()
            video_file.close()

            body = {
                "videoFile" : file_content
            }
        
            response = requests.request('PUT', location, headers=headers, data=body)
            print(response.text)
            print("status_code: ", response.status_code)

obj = youtube()
obj.resumable_uploads()
```

The response in console is as :

```
status_code:  200    
{
  "kind": "youtube#video",
  "etag": "0rZIqeGvCifiyfQymb8CKXsC6CI",
  "id": "YF2DQDACB4M",
  "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2020-08-28T17:29:12Z",
    "channelId": "UCXonQaqsiqTV_YqYsB6W4Dg",
    "title": "Video 2 by Sidra",
    "description": "This is a description of my video",
    "thumbnails": {
      "default": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YF2DQDACB4M/default.jpg",
        "width": 120,
        "height": 90
      },
      "medium": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YF2DQDACB4M/mqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 320,
        "height": 180
      },
      "high": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YF2DQDACB4M/hqdefault.jpg",
        "width": 480,
        "height": 360
      }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Sidra Sial",
    "tags": [
      "cool",
      "video",
      "more keywords"
    ],
    "categoryId": "22",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
    "localized": {
      "title": "Video 2 by Sidra",
      "description": "This is a description of my video"
    }
  },
  "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "P0D",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "sd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": false,
    "contentRating": {},
    "projection": "rectangular",
    "hasCustomThumbnail": false
  },
  "status": {
    "uploadStatus": "uploaded",
    "privacyStatus": "public",
    "license": "youtube",
    "embeddable": true,
    "publicStatsViewable": true,
    "selfDeclaredMadeForKids": true
  }
}

status_code:  200
```

[The screenshot from YouTube Channel:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eymGF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I personally would not recommend you to implement resumable video uploading using bare HTTP request methods. That's quite tricky to done it right.

It's more feasible to start from a [fully working example](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/upload_video.py), and modify it such that to fit your needs.

In any case, here is the official (quite heavy) documentation of the [Resumable Upload Protocol](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol).

---

Only having a first glance over your code, I noticed you missed passing to the first HTTP request method call -- `POST` -- the header `X-Upload-Content-Length`. (Note that I did not analyzed your code in its entirety; do follow my advise stated above.)

Comment: I have written this code by following the documentation. 
Moreover, the example you share (in the link above) is for the native applications but I'm writing this for "web type".

Comment: Also, in header for --POST-- method, I have missed X-Upload-Content-Length on purpose, since this was causing issue with file size (on runtime).

Comment: What kind of issues? The official doc say that `X-Upload-Content-Length` is a required header.

Comment: I recommended you to start from working code, *adapting it to your needs*; nota bene: you *did not specified your app requirements* within the original question posted above.